# What "of" should I replace with Saxon genitives? Avoiding too many "of"

Tags: writing-style, attributive-nouns, saxon-genitive, of-genitive

I'm trying to write a short scientific article and ended up with this sentence:

Now we show the result **of** the analysis **of** the sequences **of** events with the data from the study.

As you can see there are too many "of" and I think native English speakers don't like it.

How would you write it instead?

I could try to say
*the result of the events sequences analysis with the data from the study*.

But it sounds strange.

I know there are some general rules but coming from a different language it's not always easy to apply them.
I can't see any "possession" here.

PS:  I could even use another "of" instead of "from"
I could even use another "of"

the result **of** the analysis **of** the sequences **of** events with the data **of** the study.

Comment: So you'd like to show *the event-sequence analysis results*, right?

Comment: Is it better than my "of" version?

Comment: @skan: Absolutely.

Comment: You could replace “the analysis of” with “analyzing”.

Comment: Remember that nouns used attributively are almost always in the singular. Your examples are not grammatical using them in the plural. And what dies this have to do with apostrophe-*s* possessives? Not sure I see where you need an apostrophe at all.

Comment: @tchrist I have many sequences and each of them is composed by many events. Say for example the diseases that each person suffer along his life.

Comment: Saxon genitives always need apostrophes, so your proposed rewriting is not correct. I don’t think there’s much wrong with the original, though, except in most contexts we talk about a single sequence of events (but since I don’t know your context, I don’t know if you are in fact talking about one analysis which analysed several different sequences, each with its respective events). If you really want to get rid of an _of_, you could write “analysis into” instead – it’s rarer, but does occur. I don’t think there’s any real need, though.

Comment: @skan That does not matter: notice how all mine were in the singular.  Attributive nouns almost are. Doesn't matter that you have many of them; you still use a singular attributively. If ten dogs lived in one house, it would be the dog house singular. Thus is very important because you could not otherwise orally and aurally distinguish the attributive use from the possessive use, for they would sound the same.

Comment: @skan by the way, your suspicion that too many *of*s in a row feels awkward in English is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"events sequence" is grammatically incorrect, but "event sequence" is perfectly valid.  In general, it's incorrect to use the plural for an attributive noun.  All nouns except the final must be singular, though there seem to be weird exceptions ("Natural Sciences Research")

You could say

> the result of the event sequence analysis

Or

> the result of analyzing the event sequences

Or

> the event sequence analysis results

"The event sequence analysis result" is also grammatically correct but sounds weirder than with "results" to me.

I don't think the fact that there are multiple sequences is of much consequence here.  But if that's important to you, the most natural and grammatically correct way to state this unambiguously is:

> The result of the analysis of the event sequences

Comment: I have many sequences and each of them is composed by many events. Say for example the diseases that each person suffer along his life. And I analyze altogether, on a single analysis.

Comment: @skan yes, that much was clear from your *of* chain.  Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to be this precise about what's singular and what's plural in a noun phrase while maintaining grammatical correctness.  I doubt it's necessary to be so precise in an abstract or introduction, but that's your call.

Comment: @skan You must still use the singular for all but the last noun.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then can  I also keep my original long "of" sentence or do you suggest to use your sentences instead?

Comment: @skan I'd recommend "the analysis of the event sequences", with or without "the result of"

Comment: And I don't want to show the whole analysis (explained on a different section) process but just its result.

Can I say "the results of analyzing the events sequences"?  with plural events

Comment: @skan Yes, that is perfectly fine and reads very naturally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "events sequences" is not correct, but otherwise that sentence is fine.

Comment: @skan a sequence has more than one of something, so it's perfectly clear that each of the "event sequences" contains multiple events.

Comment: @Andy Ah, sorry, I missed that extra s. Yes, _event sequences_.